# Eclipse workspace UI layout reset

Tags: eclipse, reset

Every time I open Eclipse, I get the error:

> Unable to read workbench state.
>   workbench UI layout will be reset.

Naturally, any UI changes I have made are not saved. I have tried:

- Making sure that I have write permissions to the directory and its contents.
- Deleting the .plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench directory

I am using:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Build id: 20090621-0832

The OS I'm using it on is Windows Vista.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your plugin must cause a conflict during the startup sequence.

What your eclipse log file includes about this?
Check the ".log" file in the ".metadata" directory of your workspace.

Did you have an older version of eclipse, with a workspace you are reusing with this new version of eclipse?

Comment: Thank you. I found out that the VI plugin I use conflicted with something, so I removed it and reinstalled; it works now.